# How to go to the next input text not disabled avoiding a input text in between?

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, jquery-events

I have a table form with many variable input like this:

**id='ins_v_1'** || **id='X_1'** || **id='an1_1'** ||**_id='an2_1'_**||**_id='an3_1'_**

**id='ins_v_2'** || **id=_'X_2'** || **id='an1_2'** || **id='an2_2'** || **id='an3_2'_**

**id='ins_v_3'** || **id='X_3'** || **id='an1_3'** || **id='an2_3'** || **id='an3_3'_**

**id='ins_v_4'** || **id='X_4'** || **id='an1_4'** || **id='an2_4'** || **id='an3_4'_**

All are input texts. an#_# could be enabled or disabled. I need that if I press Tab in any input text ins_v_# go to the next input text an#__# that is enabled, avoiding the input text X_#.

For example I am in ins_v_3 and an1_3 is disabled, then if I press tab, the focus must be in the next an#_3 that is not disabled, in this case as an1_3 is disabled the focus must be an2_3.

Another example I am in ins_v_2. If an1_2 and an2_2 are disabled, then if I press tab, the focus must be in the next an#_2 that is not disabled, in this case as an1_2 and an2_2 are disabled the focus must be an3_2.

I tried this but I don't know how to do it. I was trying to get the next id that us not disables in order to put the focus on that id:

```
$j(document).unbind('keydown').bind('keydown', function (event) {
    var src_id = event.srcElement.id
    if(src_id.includes("ins_v_") && event.keyCode === 9){
    var ind = src_id.split("_")[2]
    console.log(ind);
    // for (num=1, num<4;num++ 
    //if($("an"+num+"_"+ind).next().attr("disabled", false)) {
      //  "an"+num+"_"+ind).focus(); }
   // I don't know how to get the next disabe

   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how:

```
$('[id^="ins_v_"]').on('keydown', function(e) {
    //test for tab key
    if (e.keyCode === 9) {
        //prevent tab from executing
        e.preventDefault();
        //determine the 'row number'
        let num = this.id.split('_').pop();
        //use it to find first non-disabled input and put focus on it
        $('[id^="an"][id$="_' + num + '"]').not('[disabled]')[0].focus();
    }
});
```

```js
jQuery($ => {
    $('[id^="ins_v_"]').on('keydown', function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 9) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('[id^="an"][id$="_' + this.id.split('_').pop() + '"]').not('[disabled]')[0].focus();
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><input id='ins_v_1'/></td>
<td><input id='X_1' placeholder='X_1' /></td>
<td><input id='an1_1' disabled /></td>
<td><input id='an2_1' /></td>
<td><input id='an3_1' /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input id='ins_v_2' /></td>
<td><input id='X_2' placeholder='X_2' /></td>
<td><input id='an1_2' disabled /></td>
<td><input id='an2_2' disabled /></td>
<td><input id='an3_2' /></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```